number of points in fibers
Consider a smooth irreducible projective curve $X$ over $k$. Let $K/k$ be a regular extension (e.g. $k$ is perfect and $K = k(X)$) and consider the natural projection $\pi:X_K\to X$, where $X_K = X\otimes_kK$ is obtained by base change to $K$. Consider a closed point $p\in X$ of degree $d$, I wonder if the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p) = X_K\times_X\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(p)$ always consists of a single geometric point of degree $d$. I believe this is true but I have no clue how to prove it. The intuition is in the case $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and $K = k(t)$, then an irreducible polynomial $f\in k[x]$ won't split in $k(t)[x]$ since I can specialize $t$. I'm wondering in general if we still have $p\in X$ doesn't split in the fiber although a specialization is more like saying $\pi$ admits a section.
